# I got a null pointer exception,when i get a position from cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

First,I was using managedquery.It is working fine,But the app is crashed in nexus and moto-G.That's why,I repalced getcontent resolver instead of managed query.Now,I got a null pointer exception.Please help me to resolve this issue

```
     public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
                String videoPath=null;
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                Log.i("cursor","upload-->" +cursor);
                Log.i("contentUri","upload-->"  +contentUri);
                Log.i("proj","upload-->"  +proj);

                 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

            //I got a null pointer exception here
                   int column_index = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    Log.i("column_index","Upload-->" +column_index);
                    videoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                    Log.i("videoPath","Upload-->" +videoPath );

                }
                 cursor.close();
                return videoPath;


        }
```

Comment: Please include exception stacktrace from logcat

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(23296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(23296): Process: com.tuvisioncanal, PID: 23296

 E/AndroidRuntime(23296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:4115 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.tuvisioncanal/com.tuvisioncanal.Upload}: java.lang.NullPointerException

 E/AndroidRuntime(23296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Its working for me

in onCreate() add the following

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = (YourActivity) this.getActivity();
    }
```

Then add this in Activity Result

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String path = getAbsoluteImagePath(selectedImage);
           Log.d("TAG","Image path = "+path);

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

public String getAbsoluteImagePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return uri.getPath();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your post.But i again got a same exception.

Comment: still i got a same exception